# WINAPI: GetModuleHandle and increment refcount

Tags: winapi

How can I increment refcount of the `HMODULE` returned by the `GetModuleHandle`? Can I `DuplicateHandle`, or I need to go through hops, retrieve module's path and then `LoarLibrary` on that path? In short, I want to emulate `GetModuleHandleEx` without using this function (which is XP+).

Comment: [GetModuleHandleEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that it is supported from Windows XP and above.

Comment: ... which is XP+ (==XP and above)

Comment: I misread, sorry.  You're developing for an OS older than XP?  Ouch :(  What OS are you using?

Comment: Not really, I simply didn't want to restrict generic code for xp (e.g. I also use it on WinCE)

Comment: As far as the documentation goes [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175.aspx) is _XP and above_ as well.

Comment: @Tim that's a good point. Based on the SDK headers it seems that GetModuleHandleEx is _WIN32_WINNT > 0x0500 (Win2000+)

Comment: @Tim: `LoadLibrary()` is **NOT** only available on XP and later.  All versions of Windows support it. The issue is that Microsoft does not officially support versions older than XP anymore, so MSDN has been updating all of its documentation, especially API function references, to remove mentions of those older versions. So when you read that an API function only supports XP and later, chances are it probably supports older versions as well, unless it is a new API introduced in XP specifically.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I guess everyone who has been programming for more than 5-10 years knows that LoadLibrary is available before WinXP :) The point is that if you want to support pre-WinXp you cannot rely on MSDN anymore. You have to go to WinSDK and check headers where there are proper checks based on OS version. So, GetModuleHandleEx is defined as `_WIN32_WINNT > 0x0500`, that is anything after Win2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use DuplicateHandle() on a HMODULE.  The [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724251%28VS.85%29.aspx) lists the kind of handles that DH will accept in the Remarks section, a module handle is not one of them.

One reason for this is that a HMODULE is not actually a handle at all, it is a *pseudo handle*.  There's history behind this, back in the 16-bit versions of Windows they actually were handles.  But that disappeared in the 32-bit version, they are now simply the *address* of the module where it is loaded in memory.  One pretty standard trick to convert a code address to a module handle is to use VirtualQuery() and cast the returned MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION.BaseAddress to (HMODULE).  Very handy sometimes.

Yes, the only other way to increment the reference count is to use LoadLibrary().

Comment: There is a good note by Tim. It seems that all stuff on msdn is declared as WinXP+ even thouth it might be supported by earlier OSes

Comment: @Pavel: That is correct. Now that support for Win2K has officially been dropped by MS, MSDN documentation has been getting updated to remove Win2K as the minimum OS requirement for APIs that actually do support Win2K and older OS versions. I understand the need to stop supporting old products, but I think is a very stupid move on MS's part to do a mass update of all the API documentation to reflect that.

Comment: I was actually working in a big telecom engineering firm (more than 100K employees worldwide) and they were still using Win2000 in 2009 and decided to skip WinXP but vista was such a bad product that they proffered not to upgrade ;) They were getting updated HW with Win2000 installed on them. In case of GetModuleHandleEx based on WinSDK it's `_WIN32_WINNT > 0x0500`, that is WinXP+. It's possible that it's actually was available with some SP of Win2000